# i am new to angularjs 2 framework.i need help to understand this

Tags: angularjs, django, twitter-bootstrap

How can i integrate angularjs 2 framework to my django project where i have used bootstrap.please help if you are good in angularjs 2 and bootstrap.thank you.
**how to use this because on my side its not working**

```
  npm install -g angular-cli and npm install -g @angular/cli
  ng new project-title
  cd project-title
  ng serve
```

this the error i am getting when i use these commands`npm install -g angular-cli`and `npm install -g @angular/cli`

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\harrugg>npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
npm ERR! node v7.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0

npm ERR! Cannot read property 'path' of null
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
npm ERR! node v7.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network socket hang up
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\harrugg\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-04-11T10_40_5
6_491Z-debug.log
```

**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

As you know angular 2 is a component based frontend framework to build a single page web application. To integrate angular2/4 with Django. Create a restful API with `Django` and Django `restframework` and consume those API endpoints with angular2. That is the best and recommended way to work with Django and angular2.

For instance, if you have multiple Django application you can create on of your app to angular based on other normal Django app.

You can create a folder structure like this as shown below.
[image]

Here is the link that can help you to get started with Django and angular 2.

https://4sw.in/blog/2016/django-angular2-tutorial/

Regarding your installation error, it has been already answered in stack overflow as I believe error is with the npm itself not with angular2

Check whether package.json is in your working directory 
if not create it by using `npm init` and try to install angular2 by using `npm install @angular/cli` command.

If this process didn't work. I think that the issue with npm. This link will help you to debug npm problem.
check this link. [Windows 7, npm install -g react-native-cli gives "Cannot read property 'path' of null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42390323/windows-7-npm-install-g-react-native-cli-gives-cannot-read-property-path-of)

Comment: This question is regarding an error on the Angular CLI, yet you link to an error with the React CLI.

Comment: @psych Regarding your installation error, it has been already answered in stack overflow check this link. Windows 7, npm install -g react-native-cli gives "Cannot read property 'path' of null" is not solving my problem.do u have any other way i can install

Comment: i have refereed to this link and it have the installation problem.this is the procedure  [https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/15348)  use the following commands  .                                                                                                 1` npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080`
2`npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080`
3`npm config set proxy null`
4`npm config set https-proxy null`
5`npm config set strict-ssl false`

Comment: @harri The link you posted in the comment throw 404, the other solution could be upgrading node and npm

Answer (score 0):

i have refereed to this link and it have the installation problem.this is the procedure [https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/15348)
use the following commands .

1. `npm config set proxy proxy.company.com:8080`
2. `npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080`
3. `npm config set proxy null 4npm config set https-proxy null`
4. `npm config set strict-ssl false`

you can check your network connection in case of proxy problem when using npm using the following commands

1. `npm config get registry`
2. `npm config get http-proxy`
3. `npm config get https-proxy`